# NSInternalInconsistencyException for NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add objects to an NSMutableArray but it keeps giving me this error.:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

I have researched this problem, and I'm not doing anything wrong that past people have done, so I have no idea what's wrong. Here is my code:

**Group.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *custom_desc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *attributes; //I define the array as mutable
```

**Group.m**

```
#import "Group.h"

@implementation Group
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        //do your object initialization here
        self.attributes = [NSMutableArray array]; //I initialize the array to be a NSMutableArray
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**GroupBuilder.m**

```
#import "GroupBuilder.h"
#import "Group.h"

@implementation GroupBuilder
+ (NSArray *)groupsFromJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parsedObject objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSArray *items = results[@"items" ];

    for (NSDictionary *groupDic in items) {
        Group *group = [[Group alloc] init];
        for (NSString *key in groupDic) {
            if ([group respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                [group setValue:[groupDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
            }
        }
        [groups addObject:group];
    }
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < items.count; i++) {
        //NSLog(@"%@", [[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attributes"]);
        NSMutableArray *att = [[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attributes"]; //this returns a NSArray object understandable
        Group *g = [groups objectAtIndex:i];
        [g.attributes addObjectsFromArray:[att mutableCopy]]; //I use mutable copy here so that i'm adding objects from a NSMutableArray and not an NSArray
    }

    return groups;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` on your NSJSONSerialization call.

Then all the dictionaries and arrays it creates will be mutable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you are trying to insert an object into an instance of NSArray, not NSMutableArray.

I think it is here:

```
NSMutableArray *att = [[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attrib`enter code here`utes"]; //this returns a NSArray object understandable
```

`Items` is fetched from JSON and therefore not mutable. You can configure JSONSerialization in a way that it creates mutable objects, but how exactly I don't know out of the top of my head. Check the references on how to do that or make a mutable copy:

```
    NSMutableArray *att = [[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"attributes"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: yes, I understand that, but the attributes property in my Group.h file is instantiated as NSMutableArray, and in the code in GroupBuilder.h, I made sure a NSMutableArray was being copied to it. So could you explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: actually the error is at this line `[g.attributes addObjectsFromArray:[att mutableCopy]];`

Comment: It does not really matter how you declare the references. You could even declare them as `id`. The actual type of the object you are dealing with is what it is about. Because of that you should always double check if that, what JSON has sent, is really an array or dictionary or a scalar or whatever you expect. It could be anything.

Comment: What does Group inherit from? Apparently it has got a getter (which you don't overwrite) that returns an NSArray.

Comment: The Group class is a subclass of NSObject, it doesn't inherit any methods from a different class.

Comment: Please share the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Next try, considering your replies to the first attempt:

```
#import "Group.h"

@implementation Group
-(NSMutableArray*)attributes
{
    return [[super attributes] mutableCopy];
}
@end
```